# Is it possible to implement Android push notification WITHOUT using Android's notification services

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an app for Android devices that are managed by an MDM (mobile device manager), all of the settings related to notifications have been enabled apart from one, which prevents banner notifications from showing. That setting isn't passed from the device to the MDM, so basically it's not possible for that setting to be enabled.

I was wondering if there is a way to somehow build your own notification banner implementation without using Android's support for this. I am still able to receive other types of notifications from the firebase I'm using, I get sound alerts, bubble icon on the app, and in-app notifications. Is it possible to use those as a way to trigger a custom built banner like popup?

I can't seem to find anything like this online anywhere else, which makes me think it's not possible, but also I know it's probably not a common thing.

I'm using Android's up to date tools - Kotlin, Jetpack Compose...

Comment: Perhaps, not sure, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).